# Jquery UI sortables clone "not working"

Tags: jquery, clone, jquery-ui-sortable

hope you can help with this one (or even improve it - which won't be difficult!)

I am using UI sortables and tabs.  What I can do is drag drop from column to column and manipulate the array/s to serialize it/them.

In short I have 2 cols. "col_a" and "col_b".  col_a has 2 tabs Items.  Can move from col_a to col_b but if you move "back" from col_b to col_a I want the draggable to ONLY go back into it's "parent" tab if you understand that one.

That is really what I would like to do OR only drag a clone of the draggable from col_a to col_b leaving the original in col_a.  Then somehow (best way not sure yet) to "destroy" the draggables in col_b if they are "returned" to col_a.

```
$j(function() {
$j("#col_a,#col_b").sortable({
connectWith: '.column',
helper: 'clone'         
stop : function () {
var result = $j('#col_b').sortable('toArray');
}
$j(".column").disableSelection();
});
```

Both col_a and col_b have the CSS class .column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have it working not using sortables but using draggable and droppable actually a b"better" solution for my purpose.  When I have finished the "code" I will come back and edit/update this answer